# Сворачивание/разворачивание окна приложения

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

У меня есть функция, вычисляющая по имени исполняемого файла, pid процесса.

Какие WinAPI функции нужно использовать, чтобы зная pid процесса, развернуть окно приложения на полный экран, и сделать его активным?
Приложение, к примеру, браузер Firefox.

ОС Windows 10

Answer (score 1):

Для того, чтобы развернуть на полный экран главное окно приложения, первым делом надо это окно найти:

```
DWORD dwProcessId, dwPid = 0;
HWND hWnd;

dwProcessId = ... // ID процесса, окно которого ищем

for (hWnd = ::FindWindowEx(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
     hWnd != NULL;
     hWnd = ::FindWindowEx(NULL, hWnd , NULL, NULL)) {
    ::GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, &dwPid);
    if (dwPid == dwProcessId) break;
}

_ASSERTE (hWnd != NULL);  // Еще лучше вместо ассерта сделать нормальную обработку ошибки
```

После того, как хендл окна найден, с ним можно работать обычным образом, например, вызвать

```
::ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED);
```

Comment: По-моему, найти окно можно проще...

Comment: @Qwertiy, так нажмите кнопку "Ответ" и  покажите как это сделать.

Comment: @Qwertiy, делитесь как :), у меня практически такой же код (ключевое EnumWindows + GetWindowThreadProcessId) работает уже годами, пробовал упростить, но не получалось.

Comment: @goldstar_labs, да, похоже, действительно так надо.

Answer (score 0):

Поиск окна через функцию `EnumWindows`, согласно документации (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-enumwindows) она перечисляет все top-lvl окна системы, что может быть быстрее, чем чистый `FindWindowEx`

```
HWND get_process_wnd(const unsigned long& pid)
{
    std::pair<HWND, DWORD> params = { 0, pid };

    BOOL ret = EnumWindows(
        [](HWND hwnd, LPARAM lParam) -> BOOL
    {
        auto pParams = (std::pair<HWND, DWORD>*)(lParam);

        DWORD processId;
        if (GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, &processId) && processId == pParams->second)
        {
            SetLastError(0);
            pParams->first = hwnd;
            return FALSE; // Нашли, заканчиваем перебор
        }

        return TRUE; // Не нашли, продолжаем перебор
    }
    , (LPARAM)&params);

    if (ret == FALSE && GetLastError() == 0 && params.first != NULL)
        return params.first;

    return NULL;
}
```

Использование:

```
DWORD pid = <my_pid>;
HWND hwnd = get_process_wnd(pid);

if (hwnd != NULL)
    ::ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED);
```

Comment: Спасибо! Компилится, запускается, hwnd получает, но окно почему-то не выводится и не разворачивается:( Может быть из-за того, что Win10?